# Access data from angular controller to Spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

**spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNamedDrivers", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ModelAndView saveNamedDrivers(QuotationDO user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response) {
 //public String signUp(@RequestBody QuotationDO user){ 
    System.out.println("1234567890");


    System.out.println((user));
    return new ModelAndView("premium/premium");
}
```

**index.js**

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: CONTEXT_PATH + 'saveNamedDrivers',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                data:JSON.stringify($scope.user)
            })
```

How do I access the DO object in java I m getting null data for the print statement?

[image: here is the image field getter is returning NULL]

Comment: try send ```$scope.user`` without ``JSON.stringify`` - ```data:$scope.user``

Comment: this doesn't  work @MatejMarconak